# checking for DOM attribute of svg elements using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to pass a success or failure message after running a search operation by doing this

```
// Search operation starts here
    $('#search').click(function () {
        var searchVal = $('#searchBox').val();
        var zipVal = d3.selectAll('.node').attr('zipcode');
        if (searchVal == zipVal) {
            alert('success');
        } else {
            alert('failed');
        }
    });
```

If the condition matches then passsing a success message else failure message
Here is the fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/DHATQ/11/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't choose the attribute `zipcode` of all your `.node`, what I understand your code is trying to do is searching for a zipcode and see if it is present in the nodes right ? Then the correct code would be :

```
$('#search').click(function () {
    var searchVal = $('#searchBox').val();
    var zipVal = d3.selectAll('.node').attr('zipcode');
    if (data.map(function(d) {return JSON.parse(d.zip_code.human_address).zip; }).indexOf(searchVal) != -1) {
        alert('success');
    } else {
        alert('failed');
    }
});
```

Comment: @Barnab--yes that is correct. I am trying to look for the zip. Your solution works great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the query selector capabilities of d3 to determine if a node matches that criteria, like this :

```
var zipVal = d3.selectAll('.node[zipcode="' + searchVal + '"]');
if (zipVal[0].length > 0) {      
  alert('success');
} else {
    alert('failed');
}
```

This also allows you to apply transformations on just those nodes matching the criteria, like highlighting the ones that match the search term, etc.

Source : https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections